# Android Google Maps: set boundary on 2 locations and center on one of them

Tags: android, google-maps

- I know how to set boundaries on 2 locations  so that both are shown at greatest zoom (using `LatLngBounds`)
- I know how to center on a location

Please how do I do both at the same time?

set the boundary on 2 locations **AND** center the map on one of the 2 locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`googleMap.setCenter(yourPosition);` won't change the zoom factor.

I'd just set the boundaries and then decrease current zoom factor by 1, so the map will be twice as big, then center on a position.

It's a bit dirty, but it will work, I think.

Comment: That is simple and clever. But apparently I cannot find `googleMap.setCenter(yourPosition);`

Comment: And pleas ehow do i double the zoom? :-)))  `zoom*2` is wrong

Comment: `map.setZoom(Math.round(map.getZoom()/2));` if you have other questions, refer to the API docs at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Comment: Just tested this, but it's incorrect.

If you zoom out by a factor of 1, the zoom **is already being doubled**.
The correct way to set the zoom would be `map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);`