# Google Maps: how to calculate the "double" the zoom level?

Tags: google-maps

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518287/1815311)  to [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32518044/1815311)

is a good idea for solving my problem.

Now, the problem is: how do I calculate "double" the zoom level?

---

EDIT

Meaning:

the map is looking at a square **2x2** km, I want to zoom out to look at a **4x4** km square.

---

Doing `newZoom=oldZoom*2` does not work :-(((

Comment: What does your code look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each increment of the zoom level doubles the scale.  To zoom out by a factor of two, add one to the zoom level.

```
newZoom=oldZoom-1;
```

[from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#PixelCoordinates):

> World coordinates reflect absolute locations on a given projection, but we need to translate these into pixel coordinates to determine the "pixel" offset at a given zoom level. These pixel coordinates are calculated using the following formula:
>
> pixelCoordinate = worldCoordinate * 2  <sup>zoomLevel</sup>
>
> From the above equation, note that each increasing zoom level is twice as large in both the x and y directions. Therefore, each higher zoom level contains four times as much resolution as the preceding level. For example, at zoom level 1, the map consists of 4 256x256 pixels tiles, resulting in a pixel space from 512x512. At zoom level 19, each x and y pixel on the map can be referenced using a value between 0 and 256 * 219

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SetZoom()` method:

```
map.setZoom(oldZoom * 2);
```

Also with GetZoom():

```
map.setZoom(map.GetZoom() * 2);
```

The maximum zoom level is 19 in general. 0 being the most zoomed out.

It is worth noting that is not always possible to zoom to 19 on every part of the map, here is more info about it:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom

And the parts where you can zoom further:
http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/deep-zoom.html

Comment: Thanks Slyvain, the problems is actually how do I calculate the "new" zoom level, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not still not sure what you would like to achieve but I made this. It seems silly a bit, but I really don't know what else could it be.

Code snippet:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomInButton, 'click', function () {
        if (newZoom <= 19) {

            oldZoom = newZoom;
            newZoom = oldZoom * 2; //maptOptions.zoom is the  initial oldZoom

            alert("New zoom is: " + newZoom);
            alert("Old zoom is: " + oldZoom);
            map.setZoom(newZoom);
        } else {
            alert("you have reached the maximum");


        }
    });

    // Setup the click event listener - zoomOut
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomOutButton, 'click', function () {
        if (newZoom > 1) {
            oldZoom = newZoom;
            newZoom = parseInt(oldZoom / 2); 

            alert("New zoom is: " + newZoom);
            alert("Old zoom is: " + oldZoom);
            map.setZoom(newZoom);
        } else {
            alert("you have reached the minimum");


        }

    });
```

fiddle URL:  http://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/jptLfhc8/121/

Comment: Thanks eugen, please see my edits, the problem is that if I divide by 2 the zoom level I get a MUCH MUCH MUCH bigger area...not simply form 2x2 to 4x4....