# Modifying zoom_changed event to zoom a map by 2 levels

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I modify my code for the `zoom_changed` event to support zooming in and out by levels of 2? For example, I would prefer the map to go from 11 to 13 to 15, and so on. Basically, odd level zooms only.

My current implementation results in `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error because the event keeps firing.

I know I can create custom zoom in/out buttons (as demonstrated by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32521685/1006610)), but this type of zoom functionality would only work if someone used those buttons.

I'm hoping for this zoom functionality to work for scrollwheel and pinch to zoom in/out on mobile as well.

Here's a sample of my current implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/gbrdn0sn

**code snippet:**

```js
var currentZoom;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: -33.8666,
      lng: 151.1958
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    currentZoom = map.getZoom() + 2;
    console.log(currentZoom);
    map.setZoom(currentZoom);
    document.getElementById('zoom-level').innerHTML = currentZoom;
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#current-zoom {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="zoom-level"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the error is to prevent the event from firing on the commanded "extra zoom".  One way to do that is to ignore the commanded "zoom_changed" event.

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', zoomChanged);

```
function zoomChanged() {
  // ignore zoom_changed event from this change
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    // then process the next
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', zoomChanged);
  });
  console.log("lastZoom=" + currentZoom + " map.getZoom()=" + map.getZoom());
  if (currentZoom < map.getZoom()) { // zooming in
    if (map.getZoom() % 2 != 1) {
      currentZoom = map.getZoom() + 1;
    } else {
      currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    }
  } else { // zooming out
    if (map.getZoom() % 2 != 1) {
      currentZoom = map.getZoom() - 1;
    } else {
      currentZoom = map.getZoom() - 2;
    }
  }
  console.log(currentZoom);
  map.setZoom(currentZoom);
  currentZoom = map.getZoom();
  document.getElementById('zoom-level').innerHTML = currentZoom;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gbrdn0sn/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var currentZoom;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: -33.8666,
      lng: 151.1958
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  currentZoom = map.getZoom();
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', zoomChanged);


  function zoomChanged() {
    // ignore zoom_changed event from this change
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      // then process the next
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'zoom_changed', zoomChanged);
    });
    console.log("lastZoom=" + currentZoom + " map.getZoom()=" + map.getZoom());
    if (currentZoom < map.getZoom()) { // zooming in
      if (map.getZoom() % 2 != 1) {
        currentZoom = map.getZoom() + 1;
      } else {
        currentZoom = map.getZoom();
      }
    } else { // zooming out
      if (map.getZoom() % 2 != 1) {
        currentZoom = map.getZoom() - 1;
      } else {
        currentZoom = map.getZoom() - 2;
      }
    }
    console.log(currentZoom);
    map.setZoom(currentZoom);
    currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    document.getElementById('zoom-level').innerHTML = currentZoom;
  }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#current-zoom {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="zoom-level"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @geocodzip. It clarifies a lot of things.

Comment: How come the zoom in button needs to be clicked twice before it starts zooming in? I understand that currentZoom is undefined on first click.

Comment: The `currentZoom` variable needed to be initialized, fixed in code snippet and linked fiddle.

Comment: It seems like this solution does not work with new JS Maps API renderer. For example, it doesn't work if you double click the map to zoom in, but works fine if you use the zoom in / out buttons.